# LocalStorage not working on BlackBerry Z10

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry, local-storage

I made a web app that requires localStorage.  However, my BlackBerry Z10's proprietary browser is not supporting it.  I tested support using this function:

```
function hasStorage(){
    try {
        localStorage.setItem('x', 3);
        localStorage.removeItem('x');
        return true;
    } catch (exception) {
        console.log(exception);
        return false;
    }
}
```

It is returning false and the exception being logged is: `QuotaExceededError: DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeded the quota.`

I am only trying to save some basic JSON, roughly 200 characters long.  The browser is acting like I am in "Private Mode" but I definitely am not!

Any suggestions other than switching browsers?

Comment: don't know if its the cause - but local storage can only store string based values - try setting x to be '3' and see if that helps. - also I have used Modernizr to test for the ability to use LS and that seems useful.

Comment: There tends to be a lot of "Private Browsing" issues related to ``localStorage`` for security reasons, though this one seems like the Z10 evolution browser doesn't support HTML5. Someone please correct me on this.